# live click binding with a .click event inside. Preventing recursion

Tags: jquery, recursion

I have a jquery event binding using .live that adds fancybox to the click event, then calls the click event to use fancybox.  Is there a way to prevent recursion here:

```
$('.remindMe').live('click', function (e) {
        $(this).fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'width': '235',
            'height': '375',
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'onComplete': function () {
                $('div.formControls .bigpinkbutton').click(function () {
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').text("Reminder Sent");
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').css('border-bottom', 'none');
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').css('margin-bottom', '0');
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').css('padding-bottom', '15px');
                    $('div.reminder-header span').fadeOut();
                    $('div.reminder-body p').first().html("<strong>Thank you.</strong> This notice is to confirm your product reminder email has been sent.");
                    $('div.reminder-body div.formControls').fadeOut();
                    var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id").replace("remindme", "");
                    var email = $(this).parent().find("#reminder_email").val();
                    $.post(baseURL + "SendReminder", { "email": email, "productID": id });
                });
            }
        }).trigger("click");
);
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.remindMe').live('click', function (e) {

        $(this).fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'width': '235',
            'height': '375',
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'onComplete': function () {
                $('div.formControls .bigpinkbutton').click(function () {
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').text("Reminder Sent");
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').css('border-bottom', 'none');
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').css('margin-bottom', '0');
                    $('div.reminder-header h2').css('padding-bottom', '15px');
                    $('div.reminder-header span').fadeOut();
                    $('div.reminder-body p').first().html("<strong>Thank you.</strong> This notice is to confirm your product reminder email has been sent.");
                    $('div.reminder-body div.formControls').fadeOut();
                    var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id").replace("remindme", "");
                    var email = $(this).parent().find("#reminder_email").val();
                    $.post(baseURL + "SendReminder", { "email": email, "productID": id });
                });
            }
        }).triggerHandler("click");
);
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, but I feel like there's something missing here.  if (e.whatgoeshere)?

Comment: That worked!! I'm not sure what the difference is between trigger and triggerHandler but that made all the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: You can read the difference between trigger and triggerHanler http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: `triggerHandler` does not bubble up the event, hence you don't get into recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.remindMe:not(.bigpinkbutton)').live('click', function (e) {
```

Notice `:not()` clause.

Comment: I think the problem here is that .live() updates any newly generated matching element with the event provided.  I want the click event to affect this element, but I don't want this code to be repeated when I call the click event again.. so is there a way to run this just once per generated element?

Answer (score 0):

Use the manual call syntax.

```
$('.remindMe').live('click', function (e) {
    $.fancybox({
        'href': this.href,
        'padding': 0,
        'width': '235',
        'height': '375',
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'onComplete': function () {
            $('div.formControls .bigpinkbutton').click(function () {
                $('div.reminder-header h2').text("Reminder Sent");
                $('div.reminder-header h2').css('border-bottom', 'none');
                $('div.reminder-header h2').css('margin-bottom', '0');
                $('div.reminder-header h2').css('padding-bottom', '15px');
                $('div.reminder-header span').fadeOut();
                $('div.reminder-body p').first().html("<strong>Thank you.</strong> This notice is to confirm your product reminder email has been sent.");
                $('div.reminder-body div.formControls').fadeOut();
                var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id").replace("remindme", "");
                var email = $(this).parent().find("#reminder_email").val();
                $.post(baseURL + "SendReminder", { "email": email, "productID": id });
            });
        }
    });
);
```